# Metropolis beamer theme and TikZ externalization does not correctly reset the font color after a change

Tags: beamer, tikz-external, beamer-metropolis

Using the `metropolis` `beamer` theme, I'm having an issue where, as soon as a `tikzpicture` is externalized, the font color reverts to black instead of the `metropolis` grayish default color, as evidenced in the figure below.

I tried `lualatex` and `pdflatex` (with `--shell-escape`), and my installation is up-to-date from the `MiKTeX` repository.

Of course, it is possible to manually revert the color back to the original gray, but this is cumbersome for complex pictures. Might there be a way of reverting to gray automatically?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \centering

        Externalization {\color{red}OFF} \tikzexternaldisable
        \medskip

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (0,0) {this is gray};
            \node at (0,-0.5) {{\color{blue}this is blue} and this is gray};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \bigskip

        Externalization {\color{green}ON} \tikzexternalenable
        \medskip

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (0,0) {this is gray};
            \node at (0,-0.5) {{\color{blue}this is blue} but this is black!};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: picture showing the wrong colors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a \normalcolor command at the begin of the picture: (I use brown an color for better visibility)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzifexternalizing{\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture = {\normalcolor}}}}{}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=brown} % for visibility
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \centering

        Externalization {\color{red}OFF} \tikzexternaldisable
        \medskip

        \begin{tikzpicture}\draw(0,0)--++(1,1);
            \node at (0,0) {this is gray};
            \node at (0,-0.5) {{\color{blue}this is blue} and this is gray};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \bigskip
\tikzset{external/force remake} %for the test force remake
        Externalization {\color{green}ON} \tikzexternalenable
        \medskip

        \begin{tikzpicture}\draw(0,0)--++(1,1);
            \node at (0,0) {this is gray};
            \node at (0,-0.5) {{\color{blue}this is blue} but this is black!};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]